# Movie from the 80s about a weapon which makes people evaporate

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the title of the movie I've seen on a bad quality pirate VHS in Hungary, in 1986 or 87. It was in color, and probably recent stuff then, but not sure.

It's about some special weapon. Not sure if it's some laser or some other kind. It makes people evaporate.

The only scene I can remember is taking place at a football field or stadium, during some event.

The weapon is activated. It makes the grandstand so hot, that people start jumping off it.

They show several people dying in close-up. Each of them gradually evaporates in a matter of seconds. First their clothes, then their skin, flesh, eyes etc.
I can't remember whether anything remains of them.

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laserblast?

Comment: Nope, that's not the one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Light Blast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088940/)* (original title *Colpi di luce*), 1985

[image: Movie poster for Light Blast]

> A crazed physician invents a death ray and threatens to destroy San Francisco unless he is paid $10 million.

### Trailer

Comment: Congratulations! And thank you for self-accepting. I'm going to copy a summary over for you.